# Effect of arsenic concentration on the yield of rice

Tags: regression, anova

We did an experiment to analyze the effect of arsenic levels in the soil on the yield of rice. We exchanged soil between low arsenic rice fields and high arsenic rice fields, plus we have a field in the area where we did nothing to the soil (control). At the end of harvest, we measured the yield of rice in each field. Then we took four leaf samples from the north, east, west, and south corners of each field and measured arsenic concentrations. We then took three soil samples from around each of these plants. We replicated this experiment in twenty-five areas.

At its simplest, this is a basic ANOVA problem:

Yield = B<sub>0</sub> + (Avg. Soil As level)*B<sub>1</sub> + (High As field?)*B<sub>2</sub> + (Low As field?)*B<sub>3</sub>

My question is, should I take the average soil arsenic levels in each field, or does anyone have a different method to account for the variation of arsenic levels in each field?

Comment: Second sentence has "low arsenic" twice. I am a little puzzled at the presumption that you will reduce this to ANOVA with field as a categorical controlling variable. You have many As measurements; why not aim to use as many as possible in a regression? Whether the mean is a good summary would seem to call for plant science as well as statistical expertise; perhaps the presence of really high or really low levels is crucial.

Comment: You are correct, Nick. ANOVA was the wrong term to use. The mean soil arsenic concentration will be a continuous predictor, while we control for the type of field (high As, low As, or control).

Comment: Did you randomly assign fields to be high or low in arsenic? Did you manipulate arsenic levels (perhaps by adding arsenic to the soil)? If so, this is a true experiment, & an ANOVA is an acceptable choice (whether or not it is an optimal choice is a different issue).